# Best way to map many-to-many association in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, many-to-many

I was wondering what is the best way to map a manyToMany association in JAVA. I have three tables describes like this:

```
+----------+    +-----------------+    +----------+ 
| products |    | products_stores |    | stores   | 
+----------+    +-----------------+    +----------+ 
| barecode |    | #barecode       |    | storeID  | 
| name     |----| #storeID        |----| location | 
+----------+    | price           |    +----------+ 
                +-----------------+
```

I was thniking about two ways to reprensent it in JAVA. And I would like to know which one is better in performance or anything.

***First way:***

```
    public class Product {

        private String name;
        private String barecode;
        private double price;
        private Store store;

        public Product(String name, String barecode, double price, Store store){/*...*/}
        //getter/setter
    }

    public class Store {

            private String name;
            private String location;

            public Store(String name, String location){/*...*/}
            //getter/setter
    }
```

***Second way:***

```
    public class Product {

        private String name;
        private String barecode;
        private HashMap<Store, double> priceList;

        public Product(String name, String barecode, HashMap<Store, double> priceList){//}
        //getter/setter
    }

    public class Store {

            private String name;
            private String location;

            public Store(String name, String location){/*...*/}
            //getter/setter
    }
```

My first thought was the first way, but I also thought about the second way, and I am wondering which one is better, if any. Or if there is another way better than those two.

Thank you.

Comment: Should a Product know at which Store it is sold? I would say no. Why don't you just keep things simple. A Product has a barecode, name, price. A Store has a storeID, location and list of products.

Comment: @Diyarbakir it's an app to compare price between stores, so.. Yes I need to know the store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with three objects, just as you have three DB tables:

- `Product` describes the product independent on where it's sold
- `Store` describes the store
- `ProductOffer` describes where the product is offered and for how much

Depending on your use case, list of `ProductOffer`s may be part of `Store` or `Product`, or there can be an independent container that manages the relations between products and stores using e.g. a multimap `Product` -> `List<ProductOffer>`. Or the `ProductOffer` may link to both `Product` and `Store`.

The argument for making a class for the third class is extensibility - it can easily cater for you wanting to consider product availability in the store, for example.

Comment: And what is the impact on the perf? Because, for the example if have 1 product in 10 stores, I had to create 1 product, 10 products offer and 10 stores instead of 1 products and 10 stores with the hashmap. I don't know which is better for that.

Comment: One object creation and a few bytes per offer. Wouldn't worry about that much unless / until you actually face performance problem, then you'd have to profile your application to find weak spots.

Comment: And, last question, what is the main difference with the hashmap? Because, basically the ProductOffer represent the hashmap in another class, so is it just to be close to the DB tables or is there something else?

Comment: 1. It's more readable, because you're actually having a field called something like `price`, while the `Map` approach just maps the store to a number, 2. it's easier to add another attribute of the offer (e.g. availability flag) - with `Map` you'd probably have to store that in another `Map`, or map the store to a structure holding both - which is essentially `ProductOffer` again.

Comment: Ok, you just got the best way I think! Thanks. :D

Answer (score 1):

depends on what you intend to do with the data. for example, the second way is better if you are looking to perform a lot of querying operations by the Store object. in that case the HashMap is quite handy, at the cost of memory of course. However, if your main concern is storage and there is not too much overlap in the Store class, then the first way is better as you can just create a List of Product objects and keep adding to it.

More information on your use case would help in understanding your situation better.

Comment: First thank you.
Second, it's an app to compare prices between store. The user search one product and we display a product list with the price and the related store. The Store class is basically called just to create the itinerary if the user tap on the product.

Comment: try having a List of Store objects in the Product class. Also, the price attribute should then go in the Product class. Alternatively, i think your second approach would suit you better, since you will need to display the list of stores for each product. With the HashMap, you would be able to display the Store name and price at the same time with ease

Comment: further, why have store as an internal class for product? why not create them as separate classes. then, the Product class can have a HashMap<Store,double> and the Store class can have HashMap<Product,double>. that way you can search by Store and Product. does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, thanks. So I'll go with the second way. But isn't it perf killer to use hasmap ?

Comment: for memory yes, depends on how big your data is. but it will give you immense gains in time